# Remove Item from Listbox Python

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I am trying to remove an item from a listbox that is connected to a function from my checkbutton.

```
ShrimpTempVar=DoubleVar()
ShrimpTempCheck=Checkbutton(menu,variable = ShrimpTempVar, onvalue=5.99, offvalue=0,command=ShrimpTempuraOrder) 

def ShrimpTempuraOrder():
    if ShrimpTempVar.get()==5.99:
        qty=int(QTY2Var.get())
        finalprice=ShrimpTempVar.get()*qty
        listbox.insert(END, "Shrimp Tempura")
        listboxprice.insert( END, finalprice)
    elif ShrimpTempVar.get()==0:
        listbox.delete(0,END)
        listboxprice.delete(0,END)
```

I would like the item to be removed when I unselect it.
In another post, it was suggested to do something like this:

```
listBox.Items.Delete(listbox.Items.IndexOf('Calamari'));
```

but it says that Listbox has no attribute in Items

In addition, I do not know the index number, since it changes due to the order in which I select the different checkbuttons.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

> **Question**: Remove Item from Listbox Python, if I do not know the index number

---

## Documentations

- [Python Documentation - Common Sequence Operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-common)

  ```
  s.index(x[, i[, j]])    
  index of the first occurrence of x in s (at or after index i and before index j)
  ```

  > **Note**: (8)
  >   index raises ValueError when x is not found in s. Not all implementations support passing the additional arguments i and j. These arguments allow efficient searching of subsections of the sequence. Passing the extra arguments is roughly equivalent to using s[i:j].index(x), only without copying any data and with the returned index being relative to the start of the sequence rather than the start of the slice.
- [The Tkinter Listbox Widget - get(first, last=None)](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm#Tkinter.Listbox.get-method)

  > This function returns the string corresponding to the given index (or the strings in the given index range). Use get(0, END) to get a list of all items in the list.

---

1. Get the index of a `Listbox` Item using it's label string

   ```
   label = "Shrimp Tempura"
   idx = listbox.get(0, tk.END).index(label)
   ```
2. Delete the `Listbox` Item at this index

   ```
   listbox.delete(idx)
   ```

***Tested with Python: 3.5 - TkVersion: 8.6***